# Android Studio will terminate my application run on device

Tags: android-studio, debugging, adb

When my two devices are connected to my computer and I run an application on device-A, then application starts running on device-A. But now I want to run it on device-B. When I select device-B in Android Studio, the application on device-A will be terminated. How to avoid it? By the way, I'm not debugging my application, just running it. Any help will be appreciated.

> PS:Android Studio version is 2.3.3.

Comment: Thanks  @Amaury Medeiros for editing my grammar error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio 3.0 fixed the issue.